# Comic about humans on a starship trying to escape solar system before Sun explodes/goes nova

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm remembering a comic from probably the early 1980s (USA, English) with its own characters (so no Superman, Fantastic Four, etc.) set several hundred years in the future where humans have settled the solar system, but haven't left it (I'm pretty sure they hadn't yet).

Someone figures out that the Sun is going to go Nova/Explode, and that no one has the time or resources to evacuate everyone. They secretly build a spaceship (maybe with a new type of engine?) and assemble a crew to escape the solar system. They may have mentioned taking genetic material to help colonize whatever planet they find.

The ship is powered by an AI who can use a variety of personality templates to communicate with the crew, so it can appear old, young, man, woman as directed by the crew or selected at random(?). It may have even introduced itself with something like, "Your personality of the day..."

The "bad guys" try to stop the ship, and the "good guys" escape, but one of the bad guys inserts his personality into the AI, so now his personality is the only personality the AI can use. The Sun does blow up.

I remember maybe three issues, covering the set-up, the escape and maybe some adventure in space. I don't know if there were any other issues.

I've tried this site, TV Tropes, Wikipedia and Google searches, but have found nothing so far. Does anyone out there remember this (maybe very obscure) comic?

Comment: Was there an underclass of telepaths on board the ship?  I remember a similar story involving tattoos on the telepaths and one of the telepaths being used for the warp drive.

Comment: Also does the hero jettison the genetic material provided by the government in favor of his own selection?

Comment: That suddenly sounds very familiar, yes -- more the jettisoning than the telepaths, but both do ring a bell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably Marvel's ['*Seeker 3000*'](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Seeker_3000_Vol_1).

[image: Seeker 3000 issue #1 front cover]

Comment: Could you add some more details, so the OP knows whether this is the one?

Comment: I've looked now for the title and that seems 99% like what I remembered.

Comment: Note: Seeker 3000 first appeared in *Marvel Premiere* #41. Creative team for the 4-issue series some 20 years later is completely different, and I can't recall if the mini-series seemed like it actually explicitly followed on from that first story, or was an expansion that retold that story.

Comment: http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/seeker3000.htm might have some details to use.